# Bug in survey question

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-developer-survey

[image]

It is not possible to say that I use Stack Exchange but that I have never visited Stack Overflow. If I click one, it unclicks the other.

Comment: I *think* this is better posted under [the announcement post over on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407914/take-the-2021-developer-survey); but maybe it doesn't matter, especially seeing as you're not involved with SO (hence the question in the first place lol).

Comment: It came up in the sidebar on french.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: Now we [can choose 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQNDR.png).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *intent* here is that you've never used our platform at all - because this survey will appear widely across the internet, many people who take it do not use our site. Internally here at Stack Overflow (the company) it's not uncommon to refer to the entire site - Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange Network together, as "Stack Overflow" - so that's likely why you can't pick both. You use Stack Exchange, so just choose that. Omitting checking the "Stack Overflow" box will tell us that you don't use Stack Overflow (the site).

This has been updated to make the answer option more clear!

[image: Screenshot from Developer survey - the last option now reads "I have never visited Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network"]

Comment: Is the company at all interested in which communities the answers of the survey do use? I'm a member of at least 7 communities, SO is one I search for answers on but don't participate in questions and answers generally because it seems unfriendly.

Comment: The focus of the developer survey is primarily on developers and how they use technology and less about the use of our platform, so while I think it'd be really interesting, we can generally get ideas of whether people use SO and other SE sites by reviewing activity for users through our internal databases rather than self-reported in the Survey. :)

Comment: And literal-minded folk all over the world rejoiced. (Well, not rejoiced exactly, but felt that it was nice to be accommodated and felt the urge to say "Thanks!")